# Prevent ComboBox dropdown and its AutoComplete dropdown appearance conflict

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` whose `DropDownStyle` is `DropDown`, allowing the user to type into it and its `AutoCompleteMode` is `Suggest`. The problem is that if the `ComboBox` is currently open and the user starts typing into it the auxiliary drop-down list appears but clicking on an item from it actually selects the item from the ComboBox's original drop-down list residing under the mouse at the time of click.

I would prefer if while the ComboBox's drop-down list is open the user could not type into it and would like to know if there is a more elegant solution than:

1. Setting the `AutoCompleteMode` to `None` when the `ComboBox` is open
2. Possibly changing the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` on the `OnClick` event (haven't tried, but the theory is sound)
3. Manipulating (or restricting) the entered text while the list is open
4. Similar

Comment: `Click` is not a suitable event. You can handle `DropDown` and `DropDownClosed` to disable and enable autocomplete. Also you can close the dropdown in `KeyPress` event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an option you can handle [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the `ComboBox` and close the dropdown. It keeps the autocomplete menu open, but closes dropdown:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.DroppedDown = false;
}
```

As another option, you can handle [`DropDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DropDownClosed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) events of the `ComboBox` and disable autocomplete in `DropDown` and enable it again in `DropDownClosed` event:

```
private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
}
private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
}
```

You can create a new class deriving from `ComboBox` and override corresponding  `OnXXXX` methods and put the logic there. This way you encapsulate the fix in the control class instead of handling events in your form and will have a reusable bug-free control and a more clean code.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the suggestions! But I already knew I could do it like that, I was wondering if there was another way, seeing how weird the default behavior is I thought maybe there is a flag or something I can set. I appreciate your help, but I haven't marked this answer as correct, as it is not what I am asking for, in this case. :/

Comment: You are welcome, no problem. I can't confirm these are the only solutions, but I think these solutions will be useful, specially if you encapsulate the solution in an inherited combobox to prevent making your main codes dirty.